# Ayuda con cifrado blowfish en PHP (pasar código nodeJS a PHP)

Tags: php, nodejs

Tengo datos que hay que cifrar (variable chunk):

```
e6e3 0e14 8ff0 a6a8 e1ee 968f c9a1 2c5c
35f4 078a 84ba ff2d 3123 8cc3 787e 65fa
9b20 6657 b9f2 8bbb 9786 8c56 4afd a0d4
```

(incluyo sólo las primeras 3 líneas, el resto está en [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/wHkiBN7c))

Y tengo estas lineas en nodeJS:

```js
var blowFishKey = "o=4;??v32+'4>:;6";
var cipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('bf-cbc', blowFishKey, new Buffer([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]) );
cipher.setAutoPadding(false);
chunk = cipher.update(chunk, 'binary', 'binary') + cipher.final();
```

El buffer de la primera linea es el vector de inicialización (IV).

Esto devuelve unos datos como:

```
20c3 a12a c291 29c3 a7c2 8ac2 950a c394
4635 c3a3 58c3 bd66 c39d 5828 7ac3 8345
29c2 9a62 c2ab c2a2 3a53 4760 7d45 12c3
```

(de nuevo incluyo las primeras 3 líneas, el resto está en [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/CR7QSXx3))

Vale, hasta ahí todo bien. Ahora quiero implementar la misma función en PHP pero no me devuelve lo mismo que en el nodeJS (el pastebin de arriba):

Código en PHP:

```php
$blowFishKey = "o=4;??v32+'4>:;6";
$enc = mcrypt_cbc(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $blowFishKey, bin2hex(utf8_encode($chunk)), MCRYPT_DECRYPT, "01234567");
```

No sé si el vector de inicialización está bien así, puesto que PHP en esa función sólo admite strings como parámetro IV, mientras que en nodeJS puedes pasar o un string o un array.

He probado a hacer un `bin2hex` a lo que devuelve, un `utf8_encode` y mil movidas mas, pero no hay manera, ¿alguien podría ayudarme?

Comment: Hola tengo algunas dudas: Primero pones los datos sin cifrar y luego pones un código que es para **des**cifrar y luego muestras el código cifrado. No estoy seguro si copiaste la parte incorrecta del código o que otra cosa esta pasando. *¿Puedes por favor revisar la pregunta y verificar que todo el código, la entrada y los resultados son precisos?* Por cierto, me refiero a la parte de NODE.JS. He probado el código con estos datos y obtengo otros resultados diferentes.. Gracias!

Answer (score 6):

Como dijo *Jack el Destripador*, vamos por partes. Echemos un vistazo al código ya que, como indica [rnd](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/25/rnd) en los comentarios, hay incongruencias:

`var blowFishKey = "o=4;??v32+'4>:;6";`

Parece simple, pero no lo es. Javascript trabaja con caracteres UTF-16, por lo que esa cadena **tal vez no sea convertible directamente a cadena PHP**. Aparentemente, tiene 16 **bytes**. Y, en esa cadena en concreto, **es asi**, tiene 16 **bytes**. Pero solo **en esa cadena**; no podemos asumir que todas las cadenas Javascript son `portables` directamente a PHP.

`var cipher = crypto.createDecipheriv( 'bf-cbc', blowFishKey, new Buffer( [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]) );`

Aquí, se crea un `Decipheriv`, un objeto cuya misión es **descifrar** contenidos, no cifrarlos.
Y se inicializa con un **Buffer** de *bytes*, no de texto. Esos `[ 0, 1, 2, 3 ... ]` no son **caractere**, sino **bytes**. Hay que tener cuidado al pasarlo a PHP.

`cipher.setAutoPadding( false );`

En un Decipher, sirve para que no se descarten lo bytes de 'padding' añadidos al final por el Cipher. Solo tiene sentido si se uso lo mismo en el Cipher, y suele indicar que se ha usado como 'padding' datos de usuario.
Dará problemas con PHP, a no ser que conozcas el 'padding' usado al codificar, o que el tamaño de los datos sea multiplo del tamaño de bloque de BLOWFISH, que es de 64bits (16 bytes).

`chunk = cipher.update( chunk, 'binary', 'binary' ) + cipher.final( );`

En mi versión de Node.js, ese código es inválido. Copio y pego la documentación de la versión 4.6.2 de Node.js

> cipher.update( data [, input_encoding] [, output_encoding] )
>
> Added in: v0.1.94 Updates the cipher with data. If the input_encoding
>   argument is given, it's value must be one of 'utf8', 'ascii', or
>   'latin1' and the data argument is a string using the specified
>   encoding. If the input_encoding argument is not given, data must be a
>   Buffer. If data is a Buffer then input_encoding is ignored.
>
> The output_encoding specifies the output format of the enciphered
>   data, and can be 'latin1', 'base64' or 'hex'. If the output_encoding
>   is specified, a string using the specified encoding is returned. If no
>   output_encoding is provided, a Buffer is returned.

Como vemos, los `'binary'` no aparecen por ningún lado.
Tampoco vemos como esta inicializado `chunk` aunque, por esos mismos `binary`, podemos suponer que es un Buffer, que fué inicializado en su momento como Buffer( [ XXX ] ), o bien una cadena de texto que, explicitamente, queremos tratar como BYTES crudos

En resumen: el código Node.js, tal y como está, no nos aclara mucho las cosas. Parece copiado del sitio incorrecto (y una version antigua).

Ahora, veamos la parte PHP:

`$blowFishKey = "o=4;??v32+'4>:;6";`

Lo comentado mas arriba. PHP utiliza ASCII para los caracteres. En este caso concreto, no hay problema, pero hay que ser cuidadosos.

`$enc = mcrypt_cbc( MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $blowFishKey, bin2hex( utf8_encode( $chunk ) ), MCRYPT_DECRYPT, "01234567" );`

Como dije antes, vamos por partes:

`mcrypt_cbc( ... )`

De la documentación de PHP:

> Advertencia
>
> Esta función está OBSOLETA en PHP 5.5.0, por lo tanto, será ELIMINADA
>   en PHP 7.0.0.
>
> Las alternativas a esta función son:
>
> mcrypt_decrypt()
>   mcrypt_encrypt()

Poco que añadir. Los reemplazos sugeridos están presentes desde PHP 4.0.2, PHP 5, PHP 7.

`bin2hex( ... )`

Convertimos una **cadena de texto** en otra cadena de texto, que contiene una representación hexadecimal de cada uno de los **bytes** presentes en la cadena pasada como argumento. Es decir, `bin2hex( "a" ) ==> "61"`.
No realizamos ningún procesado de la cadena, sino que tomamos sus **bytes** tal cual.

`utf8_encode( $chunk )`

Convertimos una cadena codificada en ISO-8859-1 en una cadena UTF-8. Aquí, si importa el detalle de **ISO-8859-1**, puesto que es relevante para el resultado. El resultado de esta operación, es **como minimo**, del mismo tamaño que la cadena original, pero **puede ser mas largo**.

`"01234567"`

Cadena de **caracteres**, no bytes. En bytes, eso sería **[ 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55 ]**

`MCRYPT_DECRYPT`

Función a realizar. En este caso, **decodificación**.

El resultado final de la llamada a `mcrypt_cbc( ... )` es ...
¿ Decodificar una cadena de texto cuyo contenido es la representación hexadecimal del resultado de pasar a UTF-8 una cadena de caracteres **codificada** en ISO-8859-1 ?
Esto es claramente un error. Se están confundiendo varios conceptos.

**Respuesta**

Si es un intento de portar un código de Node.js a PHP, asumiremos que el código Node.js funciona bién, por lo tanto, el fallo está en como descodificas los datos. Intenta hacer algo como esto:

```
$encryptKey = "o=4;??v32+'4>:;6"; // Esto son caracteres, no bytes.
$iv = '01234567'; // Esto son caracteres, NO los bytes que usa Node.js.
$enclaro ='<textode17bytes.>'; // 17 bytes, 136 bits. Suficiente para BLOWFISH + padding.

$hidden = mcrypt_encrypt( MCRYPT_BLOWFISH,
                          $encryptKey,
                          $enclaro,
                          MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,
                          $iv );

$final = mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, 
                         $encryptKey, 
                         $hidden,
                         MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,
                         $iv );

printf( "Sin codificar: %s strlen: %d hex: %s\n", $enclaro, strlen( $enclaro ), bin2hex( $enclaro ) );
printf( "Codificado:                      strlen: %d hex: %s\n", strlen( $hidden ), bin2hex( $hidden ) );
printf( "Descodificado: %s strlen: %d hex: %s\n", $final, strlen( $final ), bin2hex( $final ) );
```

También hay que revisar **todas las cadenas de texto** que se usen en Javascript (y sean relevantes, claro). Javascript utiliza codificación UTF-16, mientras que PHP utiliza ASCII (caracteres de 8 bits).
Puesto que no son intercambiables, desde Node.js puedes hacer:

```
function unpack( str ) {
  var bytes = [];

  for( var i = 0; i < str.length; i++ ) {
    var char = str.charCodeAt(i);
    bytes.push(char >>> 8);
    bytes.push(char & 0xFF);
  }

  return bytes;
}
```

Lo cual devuelve un Array de enteros, siendo su contenido los **bytes** de la cadena pasada como argumento `str`. Esos enteros, en PHP, se pueden convertir en una cadena así:

```
$bytes = array( 255, 0, 55, 42, 17, ... );
$string = implode( array_map( "chr", $bytes ) );
```

Además, comprueba el código Node.js por posibles usos de objetos **Buffer**, que pueden ser inicializados con **bytes**. Son reconocibles porque toman como valor un **array de enteros** `[ 1, 2, 3 ... ]`.

Otro posible punto de fallo es el uso de `setAutoPadding( false )` en el código de Node.js. Segun la documentacion de `cipher.setAutoPadding( )`:

> cipher.setAutoPadding(auto_padding=true)
>
> Added in: v0.7.1
>
> When using block encryption algorithms, the Cipher class will automatically add padding to the input data to the appropriate block size. To disable the default padding call cipher.setAutoPadding(false).
>
> When auto_padding is false, the length of the entire input data must be a multiple of the cipher's block size or cipher.final() will throw an Error. Disabling automatic padding is useful for non-standard padding, for instance using 0x0 instead of PKCS padding.
>
> The cipher.setAutoPadding() method must be called before cipher.final().

Se nos avisa que `... or cipher.final() will throw an Error.`

Es decir, si se usa esa función y **el tamaño de los datos sin codificar no es multiplo del tamaño de bloque de BLOWFISH, se producirá una excepción**.

Si esa función está en el código de Node.js, es que **se está usando un padding** propio, unos datos adicionales *en los últimos bytes codificados*. Es decir, los últimos bytes de la salida de Node.js **no tienen porque estar directamente relacionados con la el** *texto_en_claro*, así que hay que averiguar **que se está colocando ahí** para procesarlo o descartarlo. Tenemos que hacer *arqueologia* del codigo Node.js hasta que averigüemos que *puñetas* se está colocando ahí, por si es importante.

Y una última cosa. La forma correcta de comprobar si ambos códigos, el de Node.js y el de PHP , son correctos, es **descifrando** desde uno lo **cifrado** por el otro. Comparar si la salida binaria es igual en ambos es **incorrecto**. **Hay** algorritmos de cifrado que escogen *1 entre varios* metodos disponibles (de forma aleatoria, o basandose en el primer caracter del *texto en claro*, o por cualquier otro método) y *colocan* datos extra en la salida indicando el método escogido, para poder realizar la operación inversa; la salida generada por estos algorritmos no es simpre la misma, aunque el *texto en claro* si lo sea.

**AÑADIDO 1**

He modificado el ejemplo de PHP, para que muestre el *tamaño* de las cadenas, y poder observar mejor el `padding`.

Como se ve, la **longitud** de la cadena `$final` no es la misma que la de la cadena `$enclaro`. Esos bytes son *añdidos* durante el cifrado, para que el tamaño de nuestros datos coincida con el tamaño *esperado* por el mecanismo de cifrado.

Normalmente, son **0** (número, no caracter). Si colocamos nuestros *propios datos ahí*, el descifrado *nos dará problemas en el último bloque* si no sabemos exactamente que datos son.

**FIN DEL AÑADIDO 1**

**AÑADIDO 2**

Lo comento ahora. En Node.js, se utiliza la llamada al método `cipher.update( )` o `decipher.update( )` (estas pueden ser llamada múltiples veces), y se finaliza la operación de des/cifrado mediante una llamada a `cipher.final( )` o `decipher.final( )`. Esto está relacionado con su propio modo de funcionamiento, basado en operaciones *asíncronas*, que permiten mantener un programa en ejecución durante largos periodos de tiempo e ir realizando acciones *cuando se pueda* o *cuando esten disponibles los datos*.

El modo de trabajo de PHP es totalmente contrario. PHP ejecuta cada *script* *desde el principio hasta el final*, de una sola vez. Las funciones disponibles en PHP están pensadas (y optimizadas) para ello.

En el caso de des/cifrado de archivos, Node.js carga *trozitos* del archivo, los des/encripta, y va añadiendo esos *trocitos* al archivo de salida.

PHP, por el contrario, carga todo el archivo de entrada de una sola vez, lo des/encripta, y guarda el resultado final. **No** hay necesidad de una función `update( )`, tal como se aprecia en el ejemplo de arriba.

Esto viene a cuento del *padding*. Si en PHP, por algún motivo, es necesario des/codificar *en trozitos*, **hay que asegurarse de que el tamaño de los datos que usamos en cada vez sea múltiplo del tamaño del bloque del método usado**. Si usamos bloques más pequeños, PHP **añadirá** **bytes 0** a la salida.

Salida del ejemplo PHP de arriba:

```
Sin codificar: <textode17.bytes> strlen: 17 hex: 3c746578746f646531372e62797465733e
Codificado:                      strlen: 24 hex: 86cd73322cfbae673b6d5fa1567916ab8103caf93c56a686
Descodificado: <textode17.bytes> strlen: 24 hex: 3c746578746f646531372e62797465733e00000000000000
```

Esos **bytes** estarán intercalados con los **bytes** *realmente* des/codificados, lo que producirá una salida **mas larga** que la entrada. Si esos **bytes** extra son producidos al codificar, los *datos descodificados* **no coincidiran** con los datos originales.

**FIN DEL AÑADIDO 2**

Comment: wow.. un fin de semana movido..

Comment: Te dije en los comentarios de la respuesta chorra original que puse, la que borré, que responder a la pregunta me lo tomaría como algo personal :-P